# Jenkins slave goes offline with message "ERROR: Connection terminated / Connection aborted"

Tags: jenkins

One of our Jenkins slaves went offline with the following message:

```
ERROR: Connection terminated
java.io.IOException: Connection aborted: org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$MonoNioTransport@5fe56036[name=node-helloworld]
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$NioTransport.abort(NioChannelHub.java:208)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub.run(NioChannelHub.java:629)
    at 
...
jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
...
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    ... 7 more
```

We already restarted the slave and the Jenkins master. Unfortunately nothing helped. Log analysis neither.

Both, master and slave run on Windows Server 2008.

Do you know what could have caused the problem and how it can be solved?

Comment: Is the slave indeed offline when the message shows up?

Comment: The slave is on and running. But Jenkins master cannot connect it. Or vice versa.

Comment: Did you see this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28155

Comment: What version of Jenkins are you using? What is it the specs of the agent? What Java  version do you have in the agent?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Jenkins 2.6 on linux. Fixed it by upgrading the java version on the slave from Java 7 to Java 8.